# SSIS Package with SSRS report in script task doesn't work if run through agent job or TSQL

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssis, script-task, sql-agent

I have SSIS package which contains VB code in script task which downloads the SSRS report in excel sheet.  When I run the package manually from SSDT it works but when I run through agent job or TSQL it runs but no data gets populated in the excel sheet. Excel sheet of 0KB gets created when running through an agent job or script

Package has no parameters or anything which requires at runtime. I tried to populate text file with static data it works

```
Dim url, destination As String
destination = "D:/rep.xlsx"
url = "http://sagar-laptop/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fTestReport%2fReport1&rs:Format=EXCEL"
SaveFile(url, destination)
```

Comment: Probably permissions, when you run package from SSDT you are executing it as different user as SQL Server Agent. Anyway please post execution log(warning/errors)

Comment: No errors. its shows package executed successfully

Comment: to test read/write permission I tried by writing some text to txt file and it works.

Comment: It is similar to [The 32-64-Bit Horror Show](https://www.sqlserverradio.com/the-32-64-bit-horror-show/). Are you sure you have everything the same between your machine and SQL Server the same(driver jet/ace the same runtime - 32/64bit)

Comment: Is the objective to download a SSRS report as Excel somewhere? I suggest you lose SSIS and just do it in something simpler like powershell or C# or even SSRS subscription

Comment: What account is the package running as from SQL Server Agent, i.e. the "Run As" field in the job step?  And does this account have all the required permissions?

Comment: @SagarAuti ensure you do not swallow the exceptions from `SaveFile` as for sure the server agent job does not communicate with the URL